# using gte and lte with dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have a date time field in the database that stores the time when a record was entered in the database. I am trying to fetch data entered after a certain date but system is not returning any results

I have already tried tried the [image: following syntax]

```
date: {$gt : "2020-11-22"}
```

and

```
date: {$gt : "2020-08-19T00:00:00.000+00:00"}
```

How do I make the query work? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: what is the query you tried

Comment: @varman i mantioned it above

Comment: what Im asking is the full query

Comment: Please use { updatedAt: { $gt: new Date(filterDate) } }

Comment: @varman i added a screenshot. i am using match in mongodb compass and just writing what i mentioned in the problem, this is the first check i am adding.

Comment: Assuming that you have date field in ISO format e.g. `ISODate("2020-03-16T13:58:58.222Z")`, use `date: {$gt : new Date("2020-11-22")}`
If your date is in string format e.g. `"2020-11-22"` then it will work as string comparison, not date. In this case consider updating your date with new Date("2020-11-22")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like following in the `$match` stage

```
{
  $expr:{
    $gt:["$updateAt",new Date("2020-08-18")]
  }
}
```

or you can use

```
{
  updateAt:{
    $gt : new Date("2020-08-19")
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with simple `db.collection.find({date: {$gt: new Date("2020-03-19")}})`? Wouldn't it be much faster?

Comment: That's true, He has done in the aggregation, thats why I showed both. Sometimes if he needs more condition in match stage aggregation, first may help